# Could not find com.android.databinding:compiler.3.4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hey everyone how do we enable databinding in android_plugin_version = '3.4.0' ? as my android studio I install the latest version and I receive another error when downgrading the android_plugin_version = '3.4.0' to 3.2.xx.

**Project gradle**

```
buildscript {
ext {
    kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    android_plugin_version = '3.4.0'
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$android_plugin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
 }
}
```

**Module**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

 apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.xxx.com"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
  }
}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

   kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"
}
```

Syncing has no problem but when running it, I received this error

```
Could not find com.android.databinding:compiler:3.4.0.
Searched in the following locations:
```

-

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.4.0/compiler-3.4.0.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.4.0/compiler-3.4.0.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.4.0/compiler-3.4.0.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.4.0/compiler-3.4.0.jar
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.4.0/compiler-3.4.0.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.4.0/compiler-3.4.0.jar

Answer (score 8):

You are using  wrong version of the Databinding Compiler. For latest version, you can check sites like [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.databinding/library). For now latest version is 3.4.0. 
Here, you are passing wrong version:

```
 kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"
```

Instead, use this:

```
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.4.0"
```

**UPDATE**

In Android studio 3.3 and above you do not need to add annotation processor   `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"`. Just set  `dataBinding.enabled = true` in your module gradle file or like this:

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: @jake talledo try this

Comment: Bhadari thanks but it does not work either I receive an error of [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: even using latest version of kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4"

Comment: it does not work but removing the kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0" then run the auto generated binding will appear.

Comment: maybe the new version of gradle the 3.4.0 does no longer require to add kapt in our dependencies in gradle app just plain dataBinding{ enable = true }

Answer (score 2):

I simply remove the kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler$android_plugin_version" and it works the ActivityMainBinding appear in my MainActivity

**Gradle App**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

     apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

     apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

     apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

     android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xx.com"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to file>>setting>>Gradle>>android studio and check embedded maven

Answer (score 0):

update gradle plugin.

It worked for me